# Происхождение поговорки

Tags: фразеология

Почему любую подделку или нечто ненастоящее называют "липой"?

Answer (score 5):

Нашла здесь:
*(http://www.gumer.info/bibliotek_Buks/Linguist/hrapa/22.php)*
Почему иногда поддельные вещи называют **липой**? 
Действительно, липовый как синоним слову поддельный широко используется в русском языке. Правда, ни один доступный источник не объясняет такого переноса значения.
Но у меня есть предположение. Древесина липы очень мягкая, и для строительных и столярных работ абсолютно не пригодна. Зато она идеально подходит для художественной резьбы. Поэтому часто детали украшения интерьеров и декоративные накладки на мебель из твердых и дорогих сортов древесины делали именно из липы. Тонированная или позолоченная липа с виду ничем не будет отличаться от красного дерева или золотого литья. Вспомните хотя бы блистающую «золотом» пышную вычурность внутреннего убранства православных и католических храмов. Все – липа.

Answer (score 1):

Навскидку - дерево липа или что-то липкое тут ни при чем. В основе - "лепить" из уголовного жаргона, означающее в разных вариантах "врать", "не сознаваться", "выдавать себя за другого" и проч.
Кстати, само "лепить" по одной из версий - из шулерского сленга. Очки на карту, повышая её достоинство, "лепили" из предварительно заготовленной картинки-масти. В нужный момент картинка-наклейка незаметно удалялась. Обратный процесс назывался "мазать" или "втирать" - замеловывать очко, незаметно стирая мел при необходимости. Оба эти слова тоже пополнили словарный запас "фени".