# Слово «липа» со значением «подделка»

Tags: этимология, лексика, жаргон, омонимы

Собирал на днях цветочки липы для чая и задался вопросом: каким образом название такого благородного дерева, как "липа", приобрело омоним "липа" со значением "подделка", "ложь", "фальшивка"?
Также хочу поинтересоваться, является ли "липа" со значением "фальшивка", "ложь" и т. д. жаргонизмом?

Comment: ["Почему липа - синоним подлога"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/29670/181932) и ещё раньше: https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/8462/181932

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему липа - синоним подлога?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/29670/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b0)

Comment: Аллазар, в любом случае — не представляют ссылки интерес, или стали полезны — вопрос-дубликат лучше закрыть.

Comment: http://gramota.ru/biblio/magazines/nauka_i_zhizn/28_677 «Наука и жизнь» (№ 1, 2011)

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу только на эту часть вопроса: *является ли "липа" со значением "фальшивка", "ложь" и т. д. жаргонизмом?*

**Липа** в словарях:
• ***разг.*** 1. Подделка, фальшивка (обычно о документах). 2. Ложные сведения. III предик. ***разг.*** (Ефремова);
• ***прост.*** Фальшивый документ, вещь и т. п.; фальшивка (МАС);
• ***Ирон.*** Ложные, неправильные сведения (приводимые обычно сознательно с целью обмана, введения в заблуждение кого-либо). О чём-либо поддельном, фальшивом (обычно о документах) (Кузнецов).

И только в толковом словаре [Ушакова](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/850554) (1935–1940): (***прост. вульг.***, из воров. жарг.). Что-нибудь фальшивое, поддельное.

Думаю, что сегодня слово "липа" не относится к жаргонизмам, оно стало частью обычной речи и используется повсеместно.

*― Я не могу поверить этой бумаге, потому что это самая настоящая **липа*** (Владимир Войнович. Дело № 34840 (1999)).

*Если кто и сеет в умах пессимизм, так это, скорее, само правительство, которое все годы подъема невесть зачем втемяшивало стране, что подъем-то это **липовый**, из-за одних только нефтяных цен* (Александр Привалов. О начальственном оптимизме (2004) // «Эксперт», 20.12.2004).

Answer (score 0):

Липа - это очень мягкое дерево по плотности древесины, непригодное для строительства. Поэтому "липа" - обозначение некачественного строительного материала. Расширительное экстраполирование на иные, кроме строительства, сферы деятельности - применение слова как маркера непригодности по назначению, подделки.